# Why Bitcoin design is orange?

Tags: marketing

Why is Bitcoin colored everywhere in orange even when the historic late 2000's color was some yellow-ish / gold-ish? In some places e.g. the Bitcoin group at GitHub, it seems to be portrayed showing a *less informal* black color.

Some additional related doubts, maybe for other independent posts:

- Why did Core specifically choose orange for their color?
- Why is the large blockers' fork so frequently portrayed in green color?
- Why is the Wright fork so frequently portrayed in yellow color?
- Why is [testnet colored in green](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/d56c6f312c7784e30794ff71eb0b0ec94cdf15ef#diff-e2c362461524249190284150c40dd48494fb959cb5ac4c68f75edc80158b1123) and [signet colored in pale green](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/c7898bca4e1ccbc6edafd3b72eaf80df38e3af32) (in Core)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### History

As mentioned by Pieter Wuille in comments:

> The current Bitcoin logo was adopted in the reference client's version 0.5.0 in 2011 (but it wasn't until 2014 that it rebranded to the current name Bitcoin Core). The logo was designed by bitcointalk user "bitboy" here: bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1631.msg19455#msg19455, and was not intended to be specific for one piece of sofrware.

First logo created by Satoshi had golden color and BC written:

[image: bc-logo]

Satoshi updated [logo](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=64.0) which had similar color but Bitcoin symbol ₿:

[image: second-logo]

Bitboy's logo had orange color:

[image: bitboy-logo]

#### Logos and colors used in Bitcoin Core

In Bitcoin Core 4 colors are used for different networks (mainnet, testnet, regtest, signet), here's the code:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7fcf53f7b4524572d1d0c9a5fdc388e87eb02416/src/qt/networkstyle.cpp#L14

[image: bitcoin-logos-networks]

There is one more color (black) which is used at few places for Bitcoin Core:

[image: black-logo-core]

Comment: Hm, I think that testnet logo you show is a questionable contrast. The signet logo is a very questionable contrast. Thank you very much for the graphics.

Comment: Found a related read: [https://bitcoin.design/guide/getting-started/visual-language/](https://bitcoin.design/guide/getting-started/visual-language/).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Bitcoin colored everywhere in orange even when the historic late 2000's color was some yellow-ish / gold-ish? In some places e.g. the Bitcoin group at GitHub, it seems to be portrayed showing a *less informal* black color.

Orange is used everywhere as a consequence of Core having chose that color at some point. In a way, you could say it is a measurement of influence. Sometimes that's desired, sometimes not. Sometimes is conscious, sometimes not.

Really, any color or design can be used to refer the Bitcoin chain, the one that hasn't hard forked itself for a while. At your own risk: your customers could be confused by your choices.

> - Why is [testnet colored in green](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/d56c6f312c7784e30794ff71eb0b0ec94cdf15ef#diff-e2c362461524249190284150c40dd48494fb959cb5ac4c68f75edc80158b1123) and [signet colored in pale green](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/c7898bca4e1ccbc6edafd3b72eaf80df38e3af32) (in Core)?

For signet it looks like simply acknowledging the raw result of the HSV arithmetic that fitted the middle distance between orange and green.

Really, any color or design can be used to refer that signet chain. That explains why [mempool.space](https://mempool.space) deviates signet to purple, for whatever reason.

Comment: The current Bitcoin logo was adopted in the reference client's version 0.5.0 in 2011 (but it wasn't until 2014 that it rebranded to the current name Bitcoin Core). The logo was designed by bitcointalk user "bitboy" here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1631.msg19455#msg19455, and was not intended to be specific for one piece of sofrware.